# How to get only date from datetime field of one mysql table, merge similar dates and update another table by a cron job

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, cron

In my existing Mysql database I have a table recent_history  like below which have about 200k rows

```
id  report      date
1   arpit       2019-12-17 22:12:27
2   vikas       2019-12-18 08:37:23
3   mohit       2019-12-18 13:03:35
```

And now I have created one another table called all_dates with fields id (auto_increment) and date(text) and want to get only dates in this field from the recent_history table by merging similar dates like below by a daily Cron job which updates all of  it everyday so I could get latest dates according to ascending order of id.

```
id      date
1   2019-12-18
2   2019-12-17
```

I just have started learning about those technical stuffs. I know how to set cron jobs but don’t know how to code a script for it. I have searched a lot answers about Datetime and other topics but not able to code all above 3 steps in a single PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

For get only date for your datetime row you can use this:

```
$date = '2019-12-17 22:12:27';
$adjusted_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

You will need to query table with date in format '2019-12-17 22:12:27 for get the column what you want, that is date, in  descending order, from newer to older date. So you need to know how to connect to MySQL, look for PDO the most usual way to connect to database when you are using PHP.

Here a sample how to query and make something with data returned from database:

```
<?php

try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=host_name;dbname=database_name', 'user_name', 'password');
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error database connection: ", $e->getMessage();
}

$query  = "
    SELECT date FROM table_name
    ORDER BY date DESC
";

$data = $db->prepare($query);       

if ($data) {
    $data->execute();
    $result = $data->fetchALL();
    if ($result) {
        // assign the query result to a variable
        $date = $result;
    } else {
       echo "The query do not return rows.";
    }
} else {
    echo "Error to prepare query.";
}

$date_adjusted = [];

foreach ($date as $key => $value) {
    $date_adjusted[$key] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value));
}
```

You can see the array with dates in the format you want as shown below.

`var_dump($date_adjusted);`

Then, you can iterate over $date_ajusted array and insert each value of it in table you want. As you said that order of IDs will be according to date order, basically that is it.